# Dynamic programming problem: maximize the sum of the value of all positions

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization, recurrence

At a recent phone interview I was asked the following dynamic programming problem but couldn't come up with an algorithm for it:

Suppose there is a path with `n` positions. Consider the set `S = {A,B,C}`. Each position on the path has an associated non-empty subset of `S`. For each position on the path, we can choose one element from its associated subset. For a given position `i` on the path, its “value” is determined by the *total number of distinct elements* from the positions it has access to. The positions it has access to is given by the set `{i-1, i, i+1}` (for `i=1` it is just `{0,1}` and for `i=n` it is just `{n, n-1}`). We want to maximize the sum of the “value” of all positions.

So for example, if I had `n=5` and the following subsets for each position `1…5`:
`S1 = {A,C}, S2={A, B}, S3={A,B,C}, S4={A,C}, S5={A,B,C}`
Then one such possible arrangement to maximize the sum would be `[A, B, C, A, B]`, which would be `2 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 2 = 13`.

I'd like to write an algorithm that, given a list of subsets (where the nth subset corresponds to the nth position), returns the maximum sum of the value of all positions. It should be bounded by a polynomial function of `n`.

Example Input: `[['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]`
Expected Output: `13`

Given that my phone interview is already over with and that I've still been unable to solve this problem after giving it more thought, I'd rather just see a working solution at this point. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like trial and error is the best approach:  Starting from the second element, chose one from the first and third such that all 3 are unique.  Moving on to the third element, chose one from the 4th such that all 3 are unique-if this can't be accomplished go back to the previous step and make different selections, then try selecting from the 4th again.  If still can't get all 3 unique, then keep going back a step and making new selections until you run out of options

Comment: Actually scratch my previous comment.  On the second element, when you choose one from the third, you wanna look ahead to the 4th element so you prefer to choose one from the 3rd that's not in the 4th.  With the 3rd now known, chose from 1st and second to make all 3 unique if possible.  Then proceed to 4th and repeat

Comment: It seems like this would most elegantly be implemented with recursion, but I haven't given it enough thought yet.  Probably need to let it 'stew' a bit on the backburner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to solving the problem is to realize that, given an arrangement `A` with a certain `score`, the new score of `A` after appending an element `z` **depends only on the final two elements** of `A`.

Given an array ending with the (not necessarily distinct) elements `x` and `y`, the increase in score after appending an element `z` is:

```
1                                 // from z on itself
+ 1 if (z != y and z != x) else 0 // from y gaining z as neighbor
+ 1 if (z != y) else 0            // from z gaining y as neighbor
```

For your example, there are 4 possible arrangements with the first two positions:

```
Subsets:
S1 = {A, C}, S2 = {A, B}, 
S3 = {A, B, C}, S4 = {A, C}, S5 = {A, B, C}

After placing the first two elements:

[A, A] max score = 2
[A, B] max score = 4
[C, A] max score = 4
[C, B] max score = 4
```

after appending a third element (from `S3`), all possible 'last two' elements and the maximum score of any arrangement with those 'last two' elements:

```
After S3 = {A, B, C}

[A, A] max score = 5
[A, B] max score = 7
[A, C] max score = 6
[B, A] max score = 7
[B, B] max score = 5
[B, C] max score = 7
```

Here, for instance, the unique maximal score arrangement ending in `A, A` is `[C, A, A]`, although we only care about the last two values and the score.

After all five subsets, the feasible 'last two elements' of arrangements and the maximum score of any corresponding arrangement will be:

```
[A, A] max score = 11
[A, B] max score = 13
[A, C] max score = 12
[C, A] max score = 13
[C, B] max score = 13
[C, C] max score = 11
```

so we can return 13. With extra bookkeeping throughout the algorithm, we can also reconstruct the full arrangement.

---

Here's the three-variable Dynamic Programming (DP) formula:

```
DP(index, y, z) is defined as the 
maximum score for an arrangement on PathArray[0, 1, ..., index]
with final two elements [y, z], for any y in Subsets[index-1]
and z in Subsets[index]


DP(index, y, z) = max over all x in Subsets[index-2] of
                  (DP(index-1, x, y) + AddedScore(x, y, z))
```

The answer to your question is the maximum value of `DP(n-1, a, b)` for any valid `a` and `b`.

I've excluded the base case when the path has length `2`: you should directly solve for the score of the one and two element cases.

- With one element: the score is always `1`.
- With two elements: the score is `4` if the elements are not equal, otherwise, the score is `2`.

---

A Python implementation:

```py
def dp_solve(subsets):
    if len(subsets) == 1:
        return 1

    def added_value(grandparent, parent, child) -> int:
        return (1
                + (1 if child != grandparent and child != parent else 0)
                + (1 if child != parent else 0))

    pair_dict = collections.Counter()
    for x, y in itertools.product(subsets[0], subsets[1]):
        pair_dict[x, y] = 4 if x != y else 2

    for subset in subsets[2:]:
        new_dict = collections.Counter()

        for old_key, old_value in pair_dict.items():

            grandparent, parent = old_key
            for child in subset:

                new_value = old_value + added_value(grandparent,
                                                    parent,
                                                    child)

                new_dict[parent, child] = max(new_dict[parent, child],
                                              new_value)

        pair_dict = new_dict

    return max(pair_dict.values())
```

```py
my_lists = [['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
print(dp_solve(my_lists))  # Prints 13
```

Comment: @JJ55496 Sure, added that at the end. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @JJ55496 Absolutely, thanks for pointing that out, since I realized it was a bit unclear while implementing. I ended up keeping a dictionary of each possible 'last two elements', but specifying that precisely in a mathematical formula seems more awkward.

Comment: @JJ55496 Thank you very much; that was indeed a mistake. The error was in the 'added_score' formula. When appending z on a list ending in `[x, y]`, you gain +1 (from z having itself as a neighbor), (+1 if y gained a new neighbor, i.e. if (z != y and z != x)), (+1 if z gained a new neighbor, i.e. if z != y). In the second term, I was only checking `z != x` before, and didn't catch the bug since the final result on the example was coincidentally the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively certain this iterative version always produces the max, though I can't prove it.

Note: this assumes each set doesn't contain duplicates, if that's the case needs slight modification

```
if only one position in path, select any value from it's set
else:
starting from first position on path
While (not at last element of path) {
 if position set only has 1 value, select it
 else if position set has unique value not in neighbors' sets (or single neighbor for ends), select it
 else select value that's not the same as prior position, prioritizing a value that's in (next position + 1)'s set (assuming that position isn't out of bounds)
 outputArray[position] = value
 position++
}
//at last position
if only 1 value select it
else select a value different from previous
outputArray[position] = value

outputArray should now contain values from each set that maximize distinctness among neighbors
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you explain a bit more about `prioritizing a value that's in (next position + 1)'s set`? I think an O(n) solution similar to this might be possible (the one I posted is only O(n^2), but I'm not sure I understand this algorithm

Comment: Unless I missed something in the question, the size of the subsets being at most 3 was just an example, and the fact that the total unique elements was constant is also from the example. In fact, if there are `M` total unique elements in `S`, then my current answer is `O(M^2 * n)`. You're right that if there either of these two values is constant, my solution is also `O(n)`

Comment: @kcsquared the third condition simply means, always select a value that's not the same as the prior position (if one exists), but prefer any value that's also in (next position +1)'s set, ie (current position + 2).

Comment: @kcsquared For example consider [ab] [ab] [b].  Without prioritizing (currentpos + 2), you could select 'a' for the first position, which would then necessitate b for the second and b for the third, which is not optimal.  By looking ahead, you're prioritizing b for the first, which would lead to a for the second and b for the third, which is optimal.

Comment: Thanks for the example. It looks promising, but it's possible that there's some edge cases left to consider that need more work, for example if there are two values in (currentpos) that are not in (currentpos+2), which one do you prioritize?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to include some code or pseudocode for the algorithm (in any language)? I'd like to test it out and understand it better, but I don't think I understand the specifics enough to write the code myself.